# Iterating an arraylist

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a ArrayList of object as below:

Object:

```
String country;
String languages;
String number;
```

The list is as below:

```
India, Hindi, 500
India, English, 600
India, Bengali, 800
US, French, 700
Germany, German, 800
```

Above list is present in my code as:

```
List<MyObject> myList;  // this is the list I want to query
```

So there are 5 MyObject objects in the myList with values as mentioned before.

language and country properties of the object makes a unique key in my case.

So I want to fetch the corresponding number based on the language and country.

e.g. something like:

```
getNumber(India, Hindi) should return 500
getNumber(India, Bengali) should return 800
```

How to query the list in this manner ? Is it possible through Iterator ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "String number;" - is this right ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew: It doesn't matter. I want to fetch the third property (number or string) based on the first two properties of an object from an object list..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> language and country properties of the object makes a unique key in my case.

That sounds like you should quite possibly by using a map then...

> How to query the list in this manner ? Is it possible through Iterator ?

Absolutely - it'll be O(N) but it's easy enough to do:

```
// TODO: Revisit the decision to make a field called "number"
// a string...
String getNumber(String language, String country) {
    for (MyObject candidate : list) {
        if (candidate.getLanguage().equals(language) &&
            candidate.getCountry().equals(country)) {
            return candidate.getNumber();
        }
    }
    // Or throw an exception, depending on what semantics are expected
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Trying to convert myList into Map<List, String> where the List key will be formed of first two properties.

Comment: @NikunjChauhan: No, you should extract the Language/Country pair itself as a separate object, and make a `Map<LanguageCountry, String>`

Comment: Any particular reason for that ? I do not want to go for an extra class. Is it possible to do that using an inner class ?

Comment: The extra class will be about 10 lines, but your code will be _much_ better organized that way.  It's really bad code practice to key a `Map` off a `List` like that.

Comment: @NikunjChauhan: You could use a nested class, sure - it's still an extra class. But as Louis says, it'll be a significant improvement over using a list.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Achieved it using a local class inside the method itself.

Comment: @NikunjChauhan: So you were only creating *and using* the collection within the method? Sounds unusual.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Method is a rest webservice. All this to create the object which would be returned as a xml.

Answer (score 2):

The only way, with a list, is to iterate over all the objects and find the one which has the given country and language.

It would be more efficient if you made a `MyKey` class, containing the country and language, and overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` based on the two fields. You could then use a `HashMap<MyKey, MyObject>`, and get the object in constant time by calling:

```
MyObject o = map.get(new MyKey(country, language));
```

Comment: Yes. Trying to convert myList into Map<List, String> where the List key will be formed of first two properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getCodeByCountryAndLanguage(String country, String language){
    for(MyObject candidate : mylist){
        if(candidate.country.equals(country) 
           && candidate.language.equals(language)){
            return candidate.number; 
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this:

```
int getNumber(country, language) {
    int number = -1;
    for(MyObject obj : myList) {
        if(country.equals(obj.country) && language.equals(obj.country)) {
            value = obj.number;
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this using an iterator. It would roughly look like this:

```
for(MyObject m : myList) {
    if (   "India".equals(m.getCountry())
        && "Hindi".equals(m.getLanguages())) {

        return m.getNumber();
    }
}
```

However, you could also consider moving the `country` and the `language` field to a seperate class, say `MyListKey`, that has correct `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, and then using a `Map<MyListKey, String>`. Your code would then be:

```
return myMap.get(new MyListKey("India", "Hindi"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of objects is not the matter, you should change to use Map.

You can use iterator and compare input value to find the result

If you may want to sort, let consider to use Collections. The MyObject should extends Comparable